# YiiBooster TbButtonGroup buttons not working after version upgrade

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I'm currently upgrading yiibooster on a large project and after the version change no buttons work.

This is to be expected as the upgrade added a buttonType to be added to the button to signify whether this is a link / submit etc. I must also add the classes for the btn to this, as adding a buttontype of link will force it to become  rather than a

My issue is that due to the size of the project, simply going in and adding

```
'buttonType'=> 'link',
'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'btn-default'),
```

Simply won't be feasible as there looks to be a couple hundred buttons (and I'm going to guess that most of these aren't going to be links anyway, one of the buttons I've changed downloads a file but that has still needed to be a link...) that I'm not entirely sure what the purpose of are in some cases. Is there a way to default the button type somewhere so I can save some time or is it a case of gritting and bearing it manually.

Alternatively, if someone else has a smarter way to go about this it will be appreciated. I know I can save some time adding a buttontype to the buttongroup, but this will still make me have to add btn class to each button which is the same amount of copy / paste anyway.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: This happened to me too. I ended up changing the TbButton file in the package and setting these as default.

Comment: Was it safe to set the majority of them to link? I'll have a look.